# What html element to use for quoting a speech

Tags: html

I want to quote what someone has said eg:

"True friends stab you in the front." -Oscar Wilde

Is there an html element for quoting what someone said, and also for saying who the quote is by?

Comment: is it really hard to search for "html quotation"? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`<blockquote>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote) element.

Exmaple usage:

```
<blockquote cite="somesite.com">
  <p>"True friends stab you in the front." - Oscar Wilde</p>
</blockquote>
```

Gives:

> "True friends stab you in the front." - Oscar Wilde

Or you may use the [`<q>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q) element if your quotations are short.

Comment: Is it still valid if you dont have the cite attribute?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote) doesn't say anywhere it's necessary or anything like that.